# How to filter value object that has different combination of values

Tags: javascript, object, filter

```
var namePerson = [{ name: "Andi", age: "25", hobbies: ["Soccer", "Badminton"],},
                  { name: "Robert", age: "25", hobbies: ["Read", "Swim", "Soccer"],},
                  { name: "Julia", age: "28", hobbies: ["Music", "Swim"],},];

var arrayPersonFilter = namePerson.filter(function (item) { return item.age == 25;});
var arrayPersonFilter2 = namePerson.filter(function (item) { return item.hobbies == Music";
});

console.log("==========Age============");
console.log(arrayPersonFilter);
console.log("==========Hobbies============");
console.log(arrayPersonFilter2);
```

I can't filter hobbies with the same method that age filter[this is a result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMTFW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To filter from an array you can use [array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). Also, you can use arrow functions here to make it slimmer, easier to read and best practices.

```
let arrayPersonFilter = namePerson.filter(item => item.age == 25);
let arrayPersonFilter2 = namePerson.filter(item => item.hobbies.includes("Music"));
```

```js
let namePerson = [{
    name: "Andi",
    age: "25",
    hobbies: ["Soccer", "Badminton"],
  },
  {
    name: "Robert",
    age: "25",
    hobbies: ["Read", "Swim", "Soccer"],
  },
  {
    name: "Julia",
    age: "28",
    hobbies: ["Music", "Swim"],
  },
];

let arrayPersonFilter = namePerson.filter(item => item.age == 25);
let arrayPersonFilter2 = namePerson.filter(item => item.hobbies.includes("Music"));

console.log("==========Age============");
console.log(arrayPersonFilter);
console.log("==========Hobbies============");
console.log(arrayPersonFilter2);
```

Answer (score 0):

age is a value, hobbies is an array, so you need to do some check on the items in the array, maybe something like this. Not sure if includes is the right function, but hope it makes sense.

```
var arrayPersonFilter2 = namePerson.filter(function (item) { return 
   item.hobbies.includes("Music");
});
```

Comment: Ta. Rushed to get in there first ;o)

Comment: All good, feel free to mark answered if your happy.